# Angular 2 - RxJS Switch Map Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to have an infinite scrolling section in my application. To achieve this I'm using [this component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-perfect-scrollbar) to handle the scroll events and so on. When the scroll reaches the bottom of the div I'm calling a function to get more data. So far so good.

To make this function more efficient I'm trying to wait a few seconds before the call is made as well as make sure that the data is processed properly. To do this I've been looking at the example shown on the [Angular website that showcases a wikipedia search](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#listen-for-search-terms).

I have a similar setup to what is being shown in the article, my problem is that I'm getting the following error when I call `switchMap()`:

`Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'`

This is a sample of my code:

```
private scrollEndActive: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.scrollEndActive
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap(data => {
            // ... get data from server
        })
}

...

// event to trigger call to server
scrollEnd() {
    this.scrollEndActive.next(true);
}
```

With the code above this is what I'm getting:[image]

From the research I've made it seems to be an issue related to the fact that one should return the Observable ([Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115390/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-observableinput)). But in my case I'm not sure what is the issue.

I'm working with:

- Angular 4.0.1
- TypeScript 2.2.2
- RxJS 5.2.0

Comment: You have to return `Observable` What is the problem with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to return up till this point... all the code I believe will be acting upon the `Subject` when it is triggered, so I'm not understanding where I should be returning the `Observable`

Comment: `.switchMap(data => {
                return Observable.of(null)
            })` Don't forget `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` But it is just stub. I assume you want to get real observable

Comment: Ehh I feel a bit dumb... been trying something similar for a while.. must have overlooked something -_- thanks a lot! I think I will manage to get it to work - might be in need of a few mugs of coffee.. thanks again!

Comment: I wonder what's the point of using `.switchMap(data => { return Observable.of(null) })`. It looks like you don't need to be using `switchMap` at all.

Comment: In my case I'm not returning `Observable.of(null)` I'm guessing yurzui was simply showing an example

Comment: probably something more like `.switchMap(data => fetch('/api/getAnswer?data=${data}')`

Answer (score 10):

By default, an arrow function `() => {...}` has the return type `void` unless you return something.

If you want to use `switchMap` to return nothing, you can do as yurzui said in the comments, `return Observable.empty()`.

That being said, if you return an observable of null in your `switchMap`, it means that you don't need `switchMap` and you can directly use `do` operator, that doesn an action without modifying returned data. Or `mergeMap` that allows you to return a new Observable from the data you got from the original one.

Comment: Instead of `Observable.of(null)` you might want `Observable.empty()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with:

- Angular 5.1.0
- TypeScript 2.5.3
- RxJS 5.5.6

I had the same problem. I fixed put a return value into switchMap because you can't return an `undefined` or `null` value. But in case you can't return an Observable, you can return an empty array.

I had to solve an Observable chaining and I solved in this way:

```
resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return firstObservableFunc()
    .map(res => res)
    .switchMap(result => (result && result.value === 'OK') ? secondObservableFunc() : []);                        
}
```