# cannot set timeout in catcherror angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

setting timeout in catcherror shows error in angular

Argument of type `(error: any) => void` is not assignable to parameter of type `(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<{}>`.
  Type `void` is not assignable to type `ObservableInput<{}>`. [2345]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUK4J.png

```
          catchError(error => {
           if(error==403)
           {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return next.handle(this.addToken(req,  authService.getToken())).pipe();
            }, 2000);
           }

        })
```

Comment: Returning from `setTimeout` makes no sense as it is an async operation. You need to reconsider your workflow.

Comment: You can do like `return next.handle(this.addToken(req,  authService.getToken())).pipe(delay(2000));` without `setTimeout`

Comment: `return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(` try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115390/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-observableinput)

Comment: Thanks for the comments , i tried all ways but  not worked in my case so i changed my work flow :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `delay` inside the pipe, like `.pipe(delay(2000))`