# Handling Error in HTTPClient get method not working

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular11

I am trying to catch error in HTTP get message in my service file.

Here is the script:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PortfolioEpicModel, PortfolioUpdateStatus } from '../models/portfolio-epic.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http'
import { config, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

refreshPortfolioEpicsList(id:number):Observable<PortfolioEpicModel[]>{   
  this.baseUrl=this.conf.getSettings("apiUrl");
  return this.http.get<PortfolioEpicModel[]>(this.baseUrl+ "/api/pepics/"+ id.toString())
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}

errorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse){
  console.info(error.message);
}
```

But the `catchError` call shows this error:

> Argument of type '(error: HttpErrorResponse) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<PortfolioEpicModel[]>) => ObservableInput'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345)

I didn't understand how to deal with it.

I am working in Angular 11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115390/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type-observableinput)

Comment: I am really sorry, it didnt because there uses catch, mine is catchError inside pipe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `throwError` from `rxjs`.

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  console.info(error.message);

  return throwError(error.message || "server error.");
}
```

[Sample Solution with Success and Error Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pshtj5)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the errorHandler function you're passing to the RxJS catchError operator requires either to return an Observable or to re-throw the error (like @Yong Shun has shown in his answer)

You can check the official documentation here for the catchError operator: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError